# Error connecting to database mysql using pentaho 5.0

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pentaho, data-warehouse

Im triying to connect to database using pentahoo, but i have this error:

Error connecting to database [Prueba] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:

Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
    java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Error occured while trying to connect to the database

    Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
    at     org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:26)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:375)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:301)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:115)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:62)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:493)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:478)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.newConnection(Spoon.java:8211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:26)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1227)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7368)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8673)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:540)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:399)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:766)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:882)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.createResultSetUsingServerFetch(Statement.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.scanForAndThrowDataTruncation(MysqlIO.java:3183)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1349)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:740)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:882)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.createResultSetUsingServerFetch(Statement.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.loadServerVariables(Connection.java:4478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.initializePropsFromServer(Connection.java:4062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2789)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:524)
```

i have mysql-connector-java-5.0.8, some idea?

Thanks very much and sorry for my english

Comment: It is using some other driver not the one for which you have added jar. org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver. mysql driver name com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: I think you just have to restart it. here's post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634181/pentaho-data-integration-sql-connection they faced the same issue.

Comment: i resolved, i change the connector-java-5.0.8 to 3.1.14 ! thanks for your answer!!