# Pentaho Data Integration (newest version) - Not detecting MySQL driver

Tags: java, mysql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm new to this tool and I'm trying to create MySQL connection to a database but when I press the 'Test' button it apears this message:

```
Error connecting to database [MySQL (_configuracionesEF)] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2783)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:597)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.editConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:96)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3108)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3043)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.access$2300(Spoon.java:361)
at 
org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$26.widgetDefaultSelected(Spoon.java:6184)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:8022)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9277)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:515)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:490)
... 54 more

Hostname       :{LOCAL_IP}
Port           :3306
Database name  :{DATABASE_NAME}
```

Rigth now I'm just running the application file that comes inside of the folder from the download from pentaho's webpage.

---

**What I've done until now**

I've downloaded the lastest version of the MySQL Driver from MySQL's webpage.

I've unzipped the file and copied the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar` from the driver download and tried pasting into the `lib` folder and `Data Service JDBC Driver` folder.

My question is this:

Where should I paste this driver to connect properly?

Comment: The driver JAR isn't called `bin.jar`, it is called something like `mysqlconnector-j-...`.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the file you are talking of. Updating...

Answer (score 8):

For the new version of the MySQL JDBC driver (in my case version 8.1), the name of the main driver class has changed. Even if you download the driver and restart spoon, still the MySQL connector of Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) looks for the wrong class name.

The workaround would be to use the "**Generic database**" connection type in PDI and add the new class name by hand. The typical connection details would be:

```
Dialect: MySQL
Custom connection URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name   
Custom driver class name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Reference: https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-17341

Answer (score 2):

1. download Mysql connector from here: [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=489461)
2. unzip the file
3. copy only the two *.jar files into data-integration/lib/
4. restart Pentaho
5. go to: Database Connection -> choose MySql -> edit your connection info -> test connection.

this resolved my issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to this and this solution was **perfect**!

Answer (score 1):

I got to resolve the error.

I'm ashamed, but it just needed to close and open the app again.

I just want to keep it here just if somebody doesn't get to resolve this problem and find this question.